Downconversion and CFO estimation after package detection
I'm currently working on generating a function to simulate a passband transmission. In my simulation, I assume that the received signal is twice of my transmitted signal (without adding any noise and assuming a perfect channel). However, I'm encountering an issue where I get error bits after demodulation. The figure shows the contelation plot of the demodulated data (I'm using BPSK modulation).

The Carrier Frequency Offset (CFO) estimation from two repeated signals varies significantly across different positions. This variation causes my IQ plot to form a circular pattern instead of a BPSK constellation. However, I cannot find the reason. I think the reason might be lowpass filter after downconversion.
If I disable the CFO correction, the IQ plot after demodulation looks like this, which makes me belive the downconvertsion might be the biggest issue.

The eye diagram of the received signal looks like this. (somehow really worng...)

I also understand that the packet detection should be performed using the original Long Training Sequence (LTS) signal rather than the LTS after upconversion. However, I'm uncertain about the correct sequence for upsampling, pulse shaping, combining all the data, and upconversion.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on resolving these issues. Thank you in advance!
function [passbandSignal, fs, filename] = generateQAMPassbandSignal()
    % Communication system parameters
    numSymbols = 100;           % Number of data symbols
    M = 2;                      % Modulation order for 16-QAM]
    k = log2(M);                % Number of bits per symbol
    baudRate = 4e9;             % Baud rate (Symbol rate)
    fs = 64e9;                  % Sampling frequency
    fc = 4e9;                   % IF carrier frequency 
    upsampleFactor = fs / baudRate; % Upsampling factor
    filtLen = 129;              % Filter length
    rolloff = 0.25;             % Rolloff factor

    % Header, Pilots and Silence
    header = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]; % Barker code of length 13
    [lts, ltsTime, ltsFreq] = generateLTS(1);  % generate LTS
    silence = zeros(1, 500); % zeros (silence)

    % Generate random symbols for payload
    % dataBits = randi([0 1],numSymbols*k,1);
    dataBits = zeros(numSymbols*k,1);
    
    % Modulate data using 16-QAM
    modData = qammod(dataBits, M, InputType='bit', PlotConstellation=true, ...
        UnitAveragePower=true);
    modData = modData.';

    % Upsample and apply pulse shaping
    upsampledData = upsample(modData, upsampleFactor);
    % pulseShapingFilter = rcosdesign(rolloff, filtLen, upsampleFactor, 'sqrt');
    % shapedData = conv(upsampledData, pulseShapingFilter, 'same');

    % Combine all parts
    basebandSignal = [header, silence, lts, upsampledData];

    % Zero padding (multiple times of 128)
    pad = 128 - mod(length(basebandSignal), 128);
    basebandSignal = [basebandSignal zeros(1, pad)];

    % Upconvert to passband using IQ component
    t = (0:length(basebandSignal)-1) / fs;
    iCarrier = cos(2*pi*fc*t); % Cosine for In-phase
    qCarrier = -sin(2*pi*fc*t); % Sine for Quadrature-phase
    passbandSignal = real(basebandSignal) .* iCarrier + imag(basebandSignal) .* qCarrier;
    passbandLTS = passbandSignal(length(header)+length(silence)+1:length(header)+length(silence)+length(lts));

    %% Simulate received side
    rxSig = [passbandSignal passbandSignal];

    % Normalized the received signal
    rxSig = double(rxSig);
    rxSig = rxSig / max(abs(rxSig));

    % Package Detection
    [peaks, pilotRx] = findLTS(rxSig, passbandLTS);
    sigStart = peaks(1) + length(lts);
    sigEnd = peaks(2) - length(header) - length(silence) - pad - 1;
    rxPassbandDataSection = rxSig(sigStart: sigEnd);
    rxSig = rxSig(1:2304);

    % Downconvert to baseband 
    t2 = (0:length(rxSig)-1) / fs;
    iCarrier = 2 * cos(2*pi*fc*t2); % Cosine for In-phase
    qCarrier = -2 * sin(2*pi*fc*t2); % Sine for Quadrature-phase
    cutoffFreq = 100; % Set the cutoff frequency of the low-pass filter (adjust as needed)
    filterOrder = 50; % Set the filter order (adjust as needed)
    lpf = designfilt('lowpassfir', 'FilterOrder', filterOrder, ...
        'CutoffFrequency', cutoffFreq, 'SampleRate', fs);

    iComponent = filter(lpf, rxSig .* iCarrier);
    qComponent = filter(lpf, rxSig .* qCarrier);

    rxBasebandSignal = iComponent + 1i* qComponent;
    pilotSection = rxBasebandSignal(length(header)+length(silence)+1:length(header)+length(silence)+length(lts));

    % CFO estimation
    ltss = reshape(pilotSection, [64, 2]);
    angle(ltss(:,1) .* conj(ltss(:,2)))
    cfo = mean(angle(ltss(:,1) .* conj(ltss(:,2))));

    % CFO correction
    rxBasebandSignal = rxBasebandSignal .* exp(-1i*(0:length(rxBasebandSignal)-1)*cfo);
    dataSection = rxBasebandSignal(length(header)+length(silence)+length(lts) + 1:end-pad);

    % Matched Filtering and downsample
    % shapedData2 = conv(payload, pulseShapingFilter, 'same');
    % downsampledSignal = downsample(shapedData2, upsampleFactor);
    downsampledSignal = downsample(dataSection, upsampleFactor);

    % Symbol Demodulation
    P = sum(abs(downsampledSignal).^2);
    downsampledSignal = downsampledSignal / sqrt(P/length(downsampledSignal));  % normalized the signal for demodulation
    demodBits = qamdemod(downsampledSignal, M, OutputType='bit', UnitAveragePower=true);
    demodBits = demodBits(:);

    figure;
    scatter(real(downsampledSignal), imag(downsampledSignal), 'b*');
    xlabel('In-phase (I)');
    ylabel('Quadrature (Q)');
    grid on;

    % Calculate BER
    numErr = biterr(dataBits,demodBits);
    BER = numErr / numSymbols;
    errorPosition = find(dataBits ~= demodBits);

    % Display the results
    fprintf('Number of total bits: %d\n', numSymbols*k);
    fprintf('Number of bit errors: %d\n', numErr);
    fprintf('Bit Error Rate (BER): %f\n', BER);
    fprintf('Error positions: %s\n', mat2str(errorPosition'));

    %%

    % Plotting configuration
    plotSignalComponents(t, basebandSignal, passbandSignal, fs);

    % Generate the filename
    filename = sprintf('%dQAM_%dGbaud_fc%dGHz', M, baudRate/1e9, fc/1e9);
end

function [lts, ltsTime, ltsFreq] = generateLTS(normalize)
    if nargin < 1
            normalize = true; % Default is to normalize if not specified
    end


    ltsFreq = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,1,-1, ...
        -1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0];
    ltsTime = ifft(ifftshift(ltsFreq), 'symmetric');
    lts = [ltsTime, ltsTime];

        % Normalize the LTS if requested
    if normalize
        lts = lts / max(abs(lts));
    end

end

function plotSignalComponents(t, basebandSignal, passbandSignal, fs)
    figure;
    t_baseband = (0:length(basebandSignal)-1) / fs;
    
    % Plotting the In-phase (Real) Component of the Baseband Signal
    subplot(4,1,1);
    plot(t_baseband, real(basebandSignal));
    title('In-phase Component of the Baseband Signal');
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Amplitude');
    grid on;
    
    % Plotting the Quadrature (Imaginary) Component of the Baseband Signal
    subplot(4,1,2);
    plot(t_baseband, imag(basebandSignal));
    title('Quadrature Component of the Baseband Signal');
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Amplitude');
    grid on;
    
    % Plotting the Entire Baseband Signal Magnitude
    subplot(4,1,3);
    plot(t_baseband, abs(basebandSignal));
    title('Magnitude of the Baseband Signal');
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Magnitude');
    grid on;
    
    % Plotting the Passband Signal
    subplot(4,1,4);
    plot(t, passbandSignal);
    title('Passband Signal After IQ Mixing');
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Amplitude');
    grid on;
end

function plotConstellation(signal)
   figure;
   scatter(real(signal), imag(signal), 'b*');
   title('Constellation Diagram of the Modulated Data');
   xlabel('In-phase (I)');
   ylabel('Quadrature (Q)');
   grid on;
end

function cross_cor = cross_val(S, H)
window = length(H);
cross_cor = zeros(length(S) - length(H) + 1, 1);

   for i=1:length(cross_cor)
       product = S(i:i + window - 1) .* H;
       cross_cor(i) = sum(product);
   end
end

function [peaks, pilotRx] = findLTS(basebandSignalRx, lts)
   % threshold = 1;
   cored = abs(cross_val(basebandSignalRx, lts));
   % peaks = find(cored > threshold);
   [peakValues, peakIndices] = findpeaks(cored);
   [sortedPeakValues, sortedIndices] = sort(peakValues, 'descend');
   peaks = sort(peakIndices(sortedIndices(1:2)));

   pilotRx = 0;  

   figure;
   plot(abs(cross_val(basebandSignalRx, lts)))

end


You are correct that the rotating constellation is an indication of a remaining carrier frequency offset (CFO). I suspect the issue is in your CFO correction (since there should be no carrier frequency offset the way your simulation is now set up). Disable that temporarily and confirm you get the constellation you expect. If that looks fine then you can proceed in debugging your CFO correction approach directly. For that apply an $e^{j\omega_\Delta t}$ to your complex baseband signal on the transmitter side and confirm that your CFO algorithm results in  $e^{-j\omega_\Delta t}$.  (In case this relationship wasn't clear: $e^{j\omega_\Delta t} = \cos(\omega_\Delta t) + j \sin(\omega_\Delta t)$. )
I recommend applying the LTS on the baseband signal in the transmitter prior to up-conversion to passband, and detecting it on the baseband signal after CFO correction in the receiver.

I disable the CFO correction and plot the result out. Even thoguth I can have 0 BER using BPSK, the BER will become 0.5 when I increase the modulation order. I think the problem is downconversion and lowpass fileter....(I add the plot in the question)

I suspect you are also dealing with timing offset that the filtering will generate. What is helpful to me is plotting an eye diagram of the received signal prior to any decimation to the symbol rate and confirm that the correct timing offset is being selected. I won't really have the time to dive into your low level code to find the actual issue but hope this is helpful.

Do you mean the lowpass filter I'm using after downconversion will cause the timeing offset? If so, how can I correct this issue even after performing packet detection? (I attached the eye diagram in the question)

After pasting all the code into one MATLAB file, my code runs directly... So if possible, please help me solve this problem, I've been struggling with it for a long time... I will really appriciate your help:)

Also, where is the correct location for applying packet detection? Downconversion, CFO correction, package detection, downsampling, demodulation, is this the right order?

Yes filters add delay. Sorry I don’t think we’re going to be able to resolve this here in a simple Q&A forum as it’s getting into much more detailed design and debugging. Ongoing discussion in the chat is discouraged but I wish you luck in your project.
